# jQuery WYSIWYG Reccomedations

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I am looking for a WYSIWYG editor that matches a few requirements.

1. ability to customize toolbar
2. ability to customize styles of headings/paragraphs, extra styles in dropdown, etc
3. ability to upload image (to a pre-defined folder on the same server.
   **I do not want a full fledged file manager**, just a "select image -> upload image" system)
4. ability to do an "in page" preview (think wordpress) (php)
5. integrates with jQuery

I have looked at a lot of them out there, but I can't find one that matches all these requirements.

Comment: @TheifMaster - How do you do the actual numbered lists? is it just . instead of )?

Comment: Yes. Click the orange `?` button right above the editor and you'll get the help explaining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave out requirement number four then you could easily use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for this. To get requirement four working you would need to implement some code yourself to save the page in a pending state and open a preview window. At least that is how we do it in our CMS.

As for a file manager there are plenty out there for CKEditor that plug right in. We are using [the one Core Five Labs created](http://labs.corefive.com/2009/10/30/an-open-file-manager-for-ckeditor-3-0/) with a PHP connector and it provides a nice simple upload interface that our clients get on well with. There is also the commercially available [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/) from the creators of CKEditor themselves.

Comment: AFAIK there is no free file upload tool for CKEditor which allows "pasting" images to the editor but only a (commercial) file manager. You can always write something own though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I didn't see any mention of pasting in the question. There are free alternatives to CKFinder. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the Core Five Labs plugin seems to be a full fledged file manager?

Comment: @Hailwood in that case it would be trivial to write your own CKEditor file upload connector if you don't even want your users to see a file listing. Are they never going to re-use an image? Anyway have a look around for CKEditor plugins that are more closely aligned to what you need. I just mentioned that one because I have used it successfully.

Comment: Cheers, one last thing before I accept this answer, I notice in CK editor you must define your styles using javascript, is there any way that you can define them using a css sheet?

Comment: You can use a style sheet to make the text entered into the editor match your sites house style (`CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = 'css/editor.css';`). For the drop down of styles I think you can only specify it as JS or XML.